# Copy one column over another in a delimited file

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk

For instance, I needed to remove column 25 and replace it with a copy of column 22 in a simple csv file with no embedded delimiters.  The best I could come up with was the awkward looking:

`awk -F, '{ for(x=1;x<25;x++){printf("%s,", $x)};printf("%s,",$22);for(x=26;x<59;x++){printf
("%s,", $x)};print $59}'`

I would expect something like 

`cut -d, -f1-24,23,26-59` 

to work but cut doesn't seem to want to print the same column two times...

Is there a more elegant way to do it using anything typicaly available in a linux shell environment?

Comment: It's kind of sad that cut doesn't support that, it would definitely be a useful feature.

Comment: `cut` doesn't reorder columns, either: `echo -e "a\tb\tc" | cut -f 3,2,1` results in "a[tab]b[tab]c"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tell awk to replace field 25 with field 22.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=","} {$25=$22; print}' < test.csv
```

Comment: No need for input redirection - awk takes filenames as arguments.

Comment: I did not know how to print without enumerating the columns. This is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but `paste` is part of `coreutils` and should be available, but it will take some temporary files:

```
$ cat test.csv
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
$ cut -d, -f1-5 test.csv > start.txt
$ cut -d, -f3 test.csv> replace.txt
$ cut -d, -f7 test.csv > end.txt
$ paste -d, start.txt replace.txt end.txt
one,two,three,four,five,three,seven
1,2,3,4,5,3,7
```

Or, you can skip the last temporary file and use standard input:

```
$ cut -d, -f7 test.csv | paste -d, start.txt replace.txt -
one,two,three,four,five,three,seven
1,2,3,4,5,3,7
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26' |
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{21\}\([^,]*,\)\([^,]*,\)\{2\}\)[^,]*,/\1\3/'
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,22,26
```

or if you prefer:

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26' | 
sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){21}([^,]*,)([^,]*,){2})[^,]*,/\1\3/'
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,22,26
```